# Digest authentication with monero-wallet-rpc

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-rpc, rpc

I started monero-wallet-rpc on a remote server (with login and password):

```
./monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 18082 --wallet-dir ./wallets_test  --rpc-login test:test --testnet  --daemon-host node.xmr.to
```

Then I try to connect to it through node.js

But I receive an error:

```
<html><head><title>Unauthorized Access</title></head><body><h1>401 Unauthorized</h1></body></html>
```

However, when I start monero-wallet-rpc on *127.0.0.1* **with** **same** **login and password** it works just fine:

```
{ id: '0', jsonrpc: '2.0', result: {} }
```

P.S.
When I use `curl` it works fine with both (remote and local) servers:

```
IP=127.0.0.1                  
PORT=18082
METHOD="create_wallet"
PARAMS="{\"filename\":\"test123\",\"language\": \"English\", \"password\":\"\"}"
curl \
    -u ddd:ddd --digest \
    -X POST http://$IP:$PORT/json_rpc \
    -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"'$METHOD'","params":'"$PARAMS"'}' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Nodejs request example:

```
const request = require("request");

request.post(
  "http://127.0.0.1:18082/json_rpc",
  {
    forever: true,
    json: {
      jsonrpc: "2.0",
      id: "0",
      method: "create_wallet",
      params: { filename: "megatest123", password: "", language: "English" }
    },
    auth: {
      user: "test",
      pass: "test",
      sendImmediately: false
    }
  },
  function(err, res, body) {
    console.log(body);
  }
);
```

What can be the reason of such weird behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Well there seems to be quite a few [open issues](https://github.com/request/request/search?q=digest&type=Issues) using that particular nodejs library with digest auth. I suggest using another library. The fact it works with curl proves this is not a Monero issue.